# Porque o JFrame tem tamanhos diferentes entre modo janela e modo tela cheia?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Bem, estava fazendo os `setLocation` de forma que os graficos sejam compativeis com qualquer resolução de jogo. Então percebi um certo problema quanto tentei fazer um `frame.getHeight - figura.getHeight` (A figura seria a barra preta na parte inferior da imagem) e então percebi que o tamanho dela ficava errado no modo janela, mas no modo tela cheia ficava correto.

Então pelo que percebi parece que o modo janela conta a barra de titulo (com o fechar, minimizar) como parte da sua resolução. Queria saber como corrigir esse problema, pois se continuar assim não irei conseguir controlar os objetos usando o getHeight, em modo janela ele vai ficar de um tamanho e em modo tela cheia ficara de outro.

[image: JFrame em modo janela (1920x1080)]

[image: JFrame em tela cheia (1920x1080)]

Resumidamente, como pegar somente a resolução de altura da janela sem pegar o tamanho da barra de titulo.

Comment: Acho que você está querendo tornar seu `JFrame` *undecorated*, não?! Tente: `jframe.setUndecorated(true);`

Comment: Renan, o setUndecorated define se a tela ficara em tela cheia ou não. Eu preciso que meus graficos fiquem corretos tanto em tela cheia como em modo janela, mas isso não esta ocorrendo, pois mesmo que estejam na mesma resolução, os paineis possuem tamanho diferente. Exemplo: em modo tela cheia ele fica com altura de 1080, mas em modo janela fica com altura de 1060 (algo desse tipo), isso ta fazendo a posição ficar errada.